# http load generator in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This is more of design question; how would you design a http load generator in java for which you can specify number of concurrent users, the amount of time to run the test, and a list of urls to hit.

```
some_load_generator -users n1 -time n2 -urls some_file_name.txt
```

The program starts up, creates number of threads as specified by number of users, every thread reads a random url from the url file and makes a GET request. For every request, each thread records the time it took to complete the entire GET request. Every 5 seconds this program prints out the minimum, maximum, and the average time across all the requests made so far by all the threads.

How would you go about creating threads, storing the min, max, and average information and printing that information every 5 seconds.

Here is what I have thought so far:

1. The program will create a new fixed thread pool executor which corresponds to the number of users. This takes of threads life cycle management.
2. The Runnable implementation reads a line from the file makes a GET request and records the time it took.
3. **My main issue** is how to calculate min, max, and average, across all threads, efficiently since we will need to synchronize access to these variables.
4. For printing the statistics every 5 seconds, I will use a timer task that wakes up, displays the statistics and goes back to sleep. The main issue here is, how to efficiently schedule the timer task, since there are a lot of threads that are trying to update the state of the statistics while this thread is trying to print it. May be I can increase the priority of this thread as compared to others so it gets preference while execution.

Answer (score 0):

How about your threads send this data to a sort of aggregator, and then your statistics printer just pulls data from here?

This way, just before each thread finishes, they update the needed metrics in the aggregator and the statistics printer won't ever need to interfere with the running threads?

Sort of like a remote logging. So each thread does what it needs to do, and just before finishing you send the time it took to the aggregator, and the printer then just prints the data every N seconds, but getting it from the aggregator, not the thread itself (sort of like a buffer if you will).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html).  The [Aggerate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) gives the statistics what you want.

Comment: I'm more interested in the implementation details. I'm browsing through the Jmeter svn repo but if you know please point me to the classes that I should be looking at.